# Prerendering Angular 6 (for SEO) does not translate routerLink to Href

Tags: angular, prerender

I am using prerender.io to render angular 6 pages using headless chrome. The problem is that the renderer does not render the router links and the link information gets lost.

This is especially problematic, given that the purpose of rendering is SEO.

For example, a button with [routerLink]="previewLink", will be rendered to a button with no router link.

Here is a live example

**rendered page with no links**

https://prerender.io/raw-html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fiveabook.com%2Fbooks&adaptiveType=desktop

No href and no router link in the "Preview" buttons:

```
<button _ngcontent-c12="" color="accent" mat-button="" tabindex="0" class="mat-button mat-accent ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
```

**angular page with router links**

https://www.fiveabook.com/books

The buttons have dynamically generated router links.

- Initiallly, the question was in regards to href links. However, the buttons don't have href links. Nevertheless, the rendered does not render the router links in the Preview buttons so I am not sure if googlebot can see where the buttons link to.

Comment: A `button` element has no href attribute...

Comment: You are right. However, they also don't have router links in the rendered version. Does that mean the link information is lost?

Comment: The path associated to the routerLink is stored internally, and the URL is generated and accessed on click of the button

Comment: Shouldn't that mean that when we click on the Preview button in the rendered page, we should visit the url? (just as it works on the live page)

Comment: See https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink and https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkWithHref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html buttons dont have a href attribute. Simply use an **anchor element** if you want to generate a hyperlink button.

```
<a mat-button [routerLink]="...">
Link
</a>
```

Comment: Replacing <button> with <a> works for SEO purposes :)

Answer (score 1):

If I load https://www.fiveabook.com/books directly in my Chrome browser on my Mac and look for that button, I'm not seeing an href there either:

[image]

So it looks like we are rendering the page exactly as a normal Chrome browser is rendering it.

Comment: The router link you are referring to is not bound to a variable and it works. However, the router links in the Preview buttons, that are bound to variables, seem to disappear.